# How to organize training in a small business

Tags: networking, training

I am in charge of a small, small, small company of 5 people. Usually for companies of that size it is always the same problem, one person needs to do multiple things and it is always time challenging to get things done in time.

I really want to improve things and prepare company for future growth (additional employees) , but it is frustrating because it appears that I am running in circles. So I decided the best way is to organize training, keep as few possible tasks / per person. My conclusion was if everybody clearly knows what to do and how to do it, it will be possible to get better results and hire more people to follow the footsteps.

Since our core business is the most important thing, I decided to have 3 people in our main  dept. and 2 people will do support so main department runs smoothly (customer support, IT support).

1 person from the 3 person dept would be a team leader and she is assigned to:

- lead projects
- lead training
- track and report project results

Training is something that is new to our business. We have always had training, but it wasn't organized, it was ad-hoc.

```
What is the difference or use of:
- Work books
- Reference manuals
- Training manual
- Job aid

and how to efficiently organize processes:
- before training
- during the training
- after training (support, manuals, help)
```

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace. As is, your question is a bit broad. I suggest looking through our [help center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or asking for help in [chat] to focus your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so with a small group like yours it's very hard to pick a one size fits all solution.  Training gets really expensive, and you want to make sure you're spending the time and money in the areas that are most critical to the business, and giving flexibility for the company to adapt to change as time goes on.

**Staff Assignments**

I'd offer the idea the the "everyone does everything" approach is viable up to about 20 people.  In the range of 20-80 people you need to start segmenting work, and saying that certain activities are only ever done by a certain team within the company.  What you want to avoid on a 5 person team is a case where only 1 person knows how to do a certain key task, as the risk of issues due to chokepoints and people not being available in a crunch period often outweighs the inefficiency of people having to learn how to do many things.

One way to do this that worked on a small team I lead was the idea of "primary" and "secondary" in a given critical area.  For us, it was specialization for given projects - we'd always have a primary person who was the final word on how to do the work, and who was expected to do it most of the time, but we had a secondary person who could leap in at a moment's notice.  They may not be as efficient as the primary, but they were competent enough that it was unlikely that mistakes would be made.

**Knowledge Transfer**

In terms of "how do people learn to do tasks", I'd offer the idea that you want to mix on the job learning with formal training.  I'd break it down these ways:

- **Industry Knowledge** - if the person needs to learn a technical area that is common to their field or industry, assume that most people can get 80-90% of what they need on the Internet.  Plan a small budget for book requests and a simple system for making a request for that budget.  People learn differently, so one person will thrive on a site like Stack Exchange, another will like a how to or reference book, another will thrive on YouTube videos or similar.  Let the learners pick how they learn and what they need to learn, and make the general guidelines clear - for example, if you have a limited budget, give some examples of appropriate spending - 1-3 books/year, 1 bootcamp/year, etc.  That way people don't assume your supply is limitless.
- **Coordinated Process** - every company, as it grows, establishes some company specific processes.  This is what lets people work together with efficiency, even when they don't know each other well.  Information on how to do these processes won't be available on the Internet - it's better some place access controlled for the employees.  At a minimum, it should be written down and kept up to date, which means you need to appoint someone to be in charge of that.  From there, you may want to consider ways of getting new folks into the processes - buddy systems, mentorships, internal classes - any of it can work, it's just a matter of culture and style.
- **Common How Tos** - After a while, you grow a collective knowledge of what works and what doesn't in your environment.  The easy example is the development environment of an engineering group - the tools are complex, the product is complex and getting the tools to work on the product efficiently is often a matter of many design choices, historical knowledge and the existing environment.  Rather than making a new person struggle through it, you need to decide how this information gets conveyed - some groups make scripts to automate, some have documentation, some do job shadowing - the one thing I'd advocate is that sticking someone in a room and telling them how to do something is never as good as having them try and giving them help as they go.

How much of this you need will evolve over time.  It takes serious time to craft each process or how-to guide, and doing it really early, before it has become a real standard can be a big waste of time.  So there's a point where you'll figure out that if the last 3 new guys had problems, it's probably time to formalize a bit.

**Onboarding**

There's typically a problem in small groups with onboarding.  There's always a spurt along the way where there is a long gap of no new people and then the company takes off and you can hire like mad.  All of a sudden, the team that figured all sorts of things out must now figure out how transfer all that wisdom to the new folks while simultaneously doing their jobs.

That's the real curve and I'd say there's probably no way to handle it perfectly.

Tips I've seen that help are:

- Get the managers aware that regular checkins with the new person are very important
- Buddies or other ways of connecting the new person to a peer who will help them can be very useful, but only if there is a good relationship between the two people.
- Keep track of the issues the new person has, these are the main training areas that need to be addressed.  Often big problems come from inconsistencies across the team, so it can be a good test of where you may need larger training.
- Update documentation and resources right after the new person starts succeeding, so that you have recent information on what works.

**Adult Learning**

When it comes to formal training programs, use the information above as a guide for *where* to train folks.  That said, there's some general tips from an adult learning perspective:

- Different generations and different cultures have different learning styles.  The Internet generation, for example, is extremely comfortable with Internet resources, including YouTube, Q&A sites, "Googling" for answers, and absorbing information in the somewhat haphazard scattershot way that the Internet provides.  But a person in the Baby Boomer generation may find all of that very challenging and want something more structured (or not, there is no generalization that applies to everyone).
- There's a general breakdown of learning into different ways of absorbing information - for example - reading it, hearing it, writing it down, asking questions and having them answered, seeing it done, doing it yourself and getting feedback - different individuals will get more or less benefit out of a given activity, and some learning areas require certain activities - for example, sky diving pretty much has to start with non-practice activities first - listening, reading, Q&A - then with mentored activity (doing a run with an instructor some number of times), then with trying it all by yourself.  The nature of the feedback (plummeting to the grown w/out a chute) is so severe that you really want to be careful in how you train people.  OTOH, often times writing code by yourself in a new environment IS the best form of software training - there's a lot be learned by failing on your own a bit and letting the computer give you feedback.
- A real key that many training programs forget is that there's a use or loose it cycle to the human brain.  Whatever you learn in a short span of time will only stay in your brain if you activity use it some short time later.  If you learn it "just in case" and don't think about it again for half a year, it WILL be gone and have to be relearned.  Often training is "just in time" - ie, just before you need it.  But it can also be far in the future so long as there's a way of reminding people of what they know.  Taking a quiz the day after may be helpful, but taking a similar quiz every month for 6 months will really help solidify the knowledge.
- This also forms the core difference between a training guide and a reference book.  A training guide will generally give someone a complete concept that they can put into practice in the short term.  A reference book assumes that it's storing knowledge for someone to use in the long term, and that the person only needs to know to look it up in the book, they don't need it memorized.  That's why the organization of these books is often quite different.

I really feel there's no one right way for training.  It has as much to do with the group you hire and what you're trying to teach as any particular "best practice overall".   I'll say that in the last 5 years, there's been a lot of really interesting work on how we learn and how brains work that leads me to think that the best process of all is one that can change and adapt given new information - both from your employees, and from science.

Comment: very useful comment and stuff that is always good to know. I am looking to find practical ways in books or case studies how to train and share knowlede in company. Since my team is rather young (28-32) I also want to setup knowledge base (FAQ, reference manuals, job aids, forums etc), that would grow their knowlege, but I need guidelines. Like you mentioned I do not want to over train a lot of details, since it would be a waste of time in such early phase. Lot of books are about how to be a trainer, and how to teach a course, but none on how to organize knowledge in company

Comment: It's a real trick!  I felt like I could go on an on with this one, and still not cover all my thoughts.  I think that with the changing capabilities for sharing knowledge and the changes in how the generations search for and absorb information, the game is changing so fast that any book will become obsolete, unless it's centering around the human brain (which doesn't *usually* change as fast as computers!).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'll need mutual understanding for need to have the training in the first place. This will ensure that the motivation to work though the set targets is there. Do they know that you want to reorganize? do they support your plans? [Kotter's 8-step plan](http://wikireedia.net/wikireedia/index.php?title=Kotters_8_steps_for_implementing_strategy) might be useful here.

Once you've established that there is a need for training, you'll need a plan. This plan has to contain the goals for the trainee that have been well formulated (e.g. [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria))
I would certainly list the following things in such a plan:

Goals of training

Time frame in which the training has to be completed

Ways of measuring goal attainment.

Training can be organized in a couple of ways.
Of course there are formal classes and courses you can sign up for, but that usually costs quite a bit of time and money.
For technical training a mix of reading books and practising is often a good way to further proficiency. sending the employee though a certification process is a nice added bonus that confirms proficiency and adds value for the trainee as well.
If the training you want to organise is more of the organisational process type. I'd probably explain them in a lecture type of setting with some on he job support for getting proficient at the new way of working.

That being said, I can hardly imagine that there's going to be such a fixed division of labour at such a small firm. I feel that, although specialisation is a good thing and the resulting division of labour will likely improve efficiency, a team this small will probably be likely to self organize more than it is going to be directed top-down. (unless you're in the army or something)

Comment: In a company of this size, if you specialize too much, you wind up with a big portion of your organizational knowledge taking a hike if anyone leaves.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I agree, but you have to specialize to a level, because people do not want to do 10 things during a day, and eventually you have to move forward somehow.

Comment: Wow, and here I was thinking I was a person. Thanks for the correction. Even all the actual people out there may not need to do everything they're responsible for every day.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: I am not trying to say he should have his employees specialise too much. I'm actually saying that I find it hard to believe that his organisation will in fact organise/specialise the way he has drawn out in the question because of its small size.